# which jquery plugin is used here for form validation

Tags: jquery, validation

When you click on the 'Beautify Code' button  [here](http://jsperf.com/)  without filling out the form fields, you get `divs` that slide down suddenly to give the message 'Please fill out the field'. I tried with Firebug to find which jquery plugin was used there for that purpose but in vain.

Can anyone tell the name

Comment: Read the source and find out.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I said I tried with Firebug but coulld not find

Comment: They have used `required` attribute in the html.

Comment: Look at the plain source, not firebug.

Comment: for email type = `email` and url type=`url`..and no jquery plugin is used for validation.

Comment: @NabeelSheikh, custom code ?

Comment: Those are HTML5 new Input Types. Check this link : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: @NabeelSheikh, only this page (http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_email) showed that kind of `div` when an invalid email was entered. Thinking how the same thing was done in other fields in jsperf.com.

Answer (score 1):

Those are HTML5 html validations.

Check out below link:

http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#validation

A sample page could be found out here:

http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/input-required.html

Check out below link that lists out browsers that support this:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

For browsers that don't support HTML5 validations, you might want to use [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com), a feature detection library to provide fallback support. For cross browser validation, you might want to use

https://github.com/westonruter/webforms2